# Efficient way to randomly delete all items from a hashtable?

Tags: c, hashtable

Here is the scenario.

The items inserted to the hashtable contain an integer as key(or id), and a string as the value(which is irrelevant in this question)
The id assigned to each item increases linearly, for example, the 1st item has id = 1, the 2nd item has id = 2, ... the nth item has id = n. All the items are inserted in this order as well, 1st item first, then the 2nd item...

After all items have been added to the hashtable, now i like to randomly pick an id and remove the item with this id from the hashtable. Repeat this process until the hashtable becomes empty.

I am implementing this using C, and the hashtable i use is uthash : 
http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/

Any ideas?

Updates:

These ids are actually assigned to memory blocks that have been malloced. Each block of memory has a "header" struct which contains an id. There is a global variable which keeps track what is the next id number to be assigned. So if 1000 blocks have been allocated, this number will be 1001. When a block of memory gets freed, this global variable won't change. It just keeps growing when new block of memory gets malloced.

So the idea is to randomly deallocate these blocks of memory, not sequentially, to check if anything goes wrong. The dealloc function needs an id as the parameter to free the associated memory block. I can randomly pick a number from the global variable, like rand() % global_var. But after i dealloc a block, i lack a mechanism to keep track which id has been "freed" so next time don't pick this number again. So every time i got a random id, i need to check first if this id has been freed or not. The performance of the dealloc function deteriorates as more and more ids have been freed: it becomes to common that i hit multiple misses before i can pick a non-freed id.

That's when i got this idea to store all ids in a hashtable: after i randomly pick one from the hashtable, i can actually remove it so the size of the table shrinks, and next time i won't pick the same one again. The thought is still immature, maybe there's better way of doing this than using hashtable?

Comment: Why do you have to delete them in a random order if you’re deleting them all?

Comment: If you're going to delete all of them, why does the order matter?

Comment: If the id was in sequential order, why did you need to use a hash table?

Comment: I'm going to vote for this question to be closed as it's not at all clear what you're asking for. But I'm prepared to retract if you can explain (a) why the order in which you delete items from your hash table is important, (b) why you are hashing items with sequential IDs in the first place, (c) what you have tried so far, and (d) why it isn't doing what you expected.

Comment: Actually it's for testing purpose. I'll edit my question to provide more info on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an array of length N
2. Populate the array with the numbers 1 to N
3. [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) the array (arranges the numbers in random order)
4. For each number in the array delete the corresponding hash-table entry

Comment: This one looks promising to me. I'll try that, thanks!